# What is the difference between DOCUMENT_NODE, DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE and DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE?

Tags: xerces-c

Can any one explain to me what is the difference between:

- [`DOCUMENT_NODE`](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMNode.html#a6237ede96be83ff729807688e4f638c5aeb01b6e307edacb6cac1583f467da062)
- [`DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE`](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMNode.html#a6237ede96be83ff729807688e4f638c5a4cd2263028979f3fe7e9b40fd2406e4c)
- [`DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE`](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMNode.html#a6237ede96be83ff729807688e4f638c5a775f75ac4ba9124a4d33a33d3da74779)

in Xerces-C.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, still not satisfied with the answer already given?

Comment: yes satisfied. thanks for the links provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE can be used as a top level parent of a partial document. For example to implement a cut-copy-paste operation. Described in detail here: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-B63ED1A3

A DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE is the starting node of a DTD declaration starting with `<!DOCTYPE`.
Also described in detail here: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-412266927

The DOCUMENT_NODE is the root node of the node tree generated from the XML input. Please note that this is **not** the root element of the XML instance. The parse() method returns a pointer to a DOCUMENT_NODE from where you can access the complete XML. Detailed description can be found here: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMDocument.html

Comment: Two out of three - are you going to provide info on the other one?